# How to insert CSS styles into the output generated by wp_get_archives

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm new to this and would like to know where in the line above should I insert the css style.. Can anyone show me?

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'postbypost', 'limit' => 10, 'format' => 'html' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?? You didn't bother to give any detail ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to use a style attribute, I would use the `before` and `after` options like so:

```
wp_get_archives(
    array(
        'type' => 'postbypost',
        'limit' => 10,
        'format' => 'html',
        'before' => '<span style="color: red;">',
        'after' => '</span>',
    )
);
```

Where you replace `color: red;` with whatever styles you want.